# LINQ Group by and Count by column

Tags: c#, linq, count

I have a model

```
public class Document
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AttachId { get; set; }
        public Attachment Attach { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to get array of documents grouped by attachment.
First in SQL I wrote an query for grouping:

```
select d."AttachId", count(d."AttachId")
    from "Documents" d
    group by d."AttachId"
    having (count(d."AttachId") > 0)
```

But I can't repeat it in LINQ. The query

```
from docs in Documents
group docs by docs.AttachId into g
where g.Count() > 0
select new {count = g.Count(), AttachId = g.Key}
```

gives me little bit another result, like:

```
SELECT
    Count(*),
    "AttachId"
FROM
    "Documents"
GROUP BY
    "AttachId"
HAVING
    Count(*) > 0
```

Is it possible to make count by AttachId in LINQ like in SQL `count(d."AttachId")`?

Comment: Which ORM do you use? Which version?

Comment: EF Core, v5.0.6

Comment: Actually `count(d."AttachId")` means count all not null `AttachId`. But from your model it looks like this field never have null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only arising difference between your `having count(column) > 0` and EF's  `having count(*) > 0` is that your version excludes nulls..

..so just filter them out in the LINQ if they're coming through and it's a problem

```
from docs in Documents

where docs.AttachId != null

group docs by docs.AttachId into g
where g.Count() > 0
select new {count = g.Count(), AttachId = g.Key}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use this variant. Seems it's impossible to translate LINQ into `Count(AttachId)`

Comment: I can't imagine they'd execute any different, to be honest; by the time the optimizer has finished rewriting the query again it doesn't matter much what EF generates :)

Answer (score 0):

Your hand written sql code

```
select d."AttachId", count(d."AttachId")
    from "Documents" d
    group by d."AttachId"
    having (count(d."AttachId") > 0)
```

is the equivalent of this whats generated by EF Core.
The only different things are: `SELECT Count(*), ...` and `HAVING Count(*) > 0` which is the same as writing `SELECT Count(AttachId)` and `HAVING Count(AttachId)` because row count will be the same for all fields.

Comment: No. Count(*) > 0 return columns with null and it's count.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

*linq syntax*

```
var result = (from d in Documents
      group d by d.AttachId into grp
      select new
      {
         AttachId = grp.Key,
         Items = grp
      }).Where(a => a.Items.Count() > 0).ToList();
```

*lambda syntax*

```
var result = Documents
     .GroupBy(a => a.AttachId)
     .Select(a => new
     {
        AttachId = a.Key,
        Items = a
     })
     .Where(a => a.Items.Count() > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: The same - `Count(*)` :(

Comment: Thanks, but now query gives me error "You should explicitly specify selected fields for server-side GroupBy() call or add AsEnumerable() call before GroupBy() to perform client-side grouping.". Clients side grouping is a bad for this case.